# dropping a global temporary table

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, temp-tables

2 Separate questions.

1. I am using this script to drop a table  [SOLVED]

   ```
   BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE_NAME';
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Global table TABLE_NAME Dropped');
       EXCEPTION
           WHEN OTHERS THEN
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Global table TABLE_NAME Doesn''t exist.');
   END;
   /
   ```

Is there anyway I can differentiate if table "doesn't exist" or it is being used in some other sessions (in that case it would locked and couldn't be deleted). I am not sure if I can see that table exists in user_tables. I am not fully aware of permissions.

I have added this code now

```
WHEN OTHERS THEN
        i_code  :=  SQLCODE;
        v_errm  :=  SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 64);
  if i_code = -942 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('TABLE_NAME doesn''t exist. Script will continue to create it');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Error dropping temporary table. The error code is ' || i_code || '- ' || v_errm);
  END IF ;
```

2. I see **.** at the end of each procedure like this

```
END PROCEDURE_NAME;
.
/
sho err;
```

I just don't understand why **.** is here. Is it syntax or what?

Comment: Is the table really a global temporary table? (`create global temporary table ....`) If so, why are you dropping it? Is this part of an install script? If not, maybe a global temporary table would meet your needs, without needing to drop it.

Comment: well we ran into "already exist" issue and somehow, its not being confirmed from productino environment what is the state of the table. This table isn't part of install script its part of separate procedure.

Comment: I don't understand, why did you run into an already exist issue with a global temporary table. The table should already exist, and the code just uses (insert, delete, update, etc) it.

Comment: @Nader 's answer work for me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Step 1. Figure out which errors you want to trap:

If the table does not exist:

```
SQL> drop table x;
drop table x
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

If the table is in use:

```
SQL> create global temporary table t (data varchar2(4000));

Table created.
```

Use the table in another session. (Notice no commit or anything after the insert.)

```
SQL> insert into t values ('whatever');

1 row created.
```

Back in the first session, attempt to drop:

```
SQL> drop table t;
drop table t
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use
```

So the two errors to trap:

1. ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
2. ORA-14452: attempt to
   create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use

See if the errors are [predefined](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm#784). They aren't. So they need to be defined like so:

```
create or replace procedure p as
    table_or_view_not_exist exception;
    pragma exception_init(table_or_view_not_exist, -942);
    attempted_ddl_on_in_use_GTT exception;
    pragma exception_init(attempted_ddl_on_in_use_GTT, -14452);
begin
    execute immediate 'drop table t';

    exception 
        when table_or_view_not_exist then
            dbms_output.put_line('Table t did not exist at time of drop. Continuing....');

        when attempted_ddl_on_in_use_GTT then
            dbms_output.put_line('Help!!!! Someone is keeping from doing my job!');
            dbms_output.put_line('Please rescue me');
            raise;
end p;
```

And results, first without `t`:

```
SQL> drop table t;

Table dropped.

SQL> exec p;
Table t did not exist at time of drop. Continuing....

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

And now, with `t` in use:

```
SQL> create global temporary table t (data varchar2(4000));

Table created.
```

In another session:

```
SQL> insert into t values (null);

1 row created.
```

And then in the first session:

```
SQL> exec p;
Help!!!! Someone is keeping from doing my job!
Please rescue me
BEGIN p; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA_NAME.P", line 16
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 26):

```
-- First Truncate temporary table
SQL> TRUNCATE TABLE test_temp1;

-- Then Drop temporary table
SQL> DROP TABLE test_temp1;
```

Comment: It worked in my case after reconnecting (changing the session).

Comment: This is the top answer!

Answer (score -1):

yes - the engine will throw different exceptions for different conditions.

you will change this part to catch the exception and do something different

```
  EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
```

here is a reference

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm

Comment: Thats the question. What would be other exception for this here (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm)

Answer (score -1):

The DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE statement defines a temporary table for the current connection.

These tables do not reside in the system catalogs and are not persistent.

Temporary tables exist only during the connection that declared them and cannot be referenced outside of that connection.

When the connection closes, the rows of the table are deleted, and the in-memory description of the temporary table is dropped.

For your reference http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefdeclaretemptable.html

Comment: You are talking about a different database product than OP. For Oracle Database http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#CNCPT1138. & "In Oracle global temporary tables are permanent objects that store temporary session specific (or transaction specific) data." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682360/sql-server-oracle-private-temporary-tables

Answer (score -2):

1. Down the apache server by running below in `putty`
   `cd $ADMIN_SCRIPTS_HOME`
   `./adstpall.sh`
2. Drop the Global temporary tables
   `drop table t;`

This will workout..