# Oracle hierarchical query on non-hierarchical data

Tags: sql, oracle, data-structures, plsql

I hava data in an Oracle table that is organized as a graph that can contain cycles (see example).

```
     CREATE TABLE T (parent INTEGER, child INTEGER)
               AS select 1 parent, 2 child from dual
        union all select 1 parent, 8 child from dual
        union all select 2 parent, 3 child from dual
        union all select 2 parent, 4 child from dual
        union all select 2 parent, 8 child from dual
        union all select 3 parent, 4 child from dual
        union all select 3 parent, 6 child from dual
        union all select 4 parent, 5 child from dual
        union all select 5 parent, 8 child from dual
        union all select 6 parent, 5 child from dual
        union all select 7 parent, 3 child from dual
        union all select 7 parent, 5 child from dual
        union all select 8 parent, 6 child from dual
```

[image: Data sample]

My goal is to get **all nodes that are descendants (children, children of children, etc.) of node X. Let's say 2**. My expected result is then: 3, 4, 5, 6, 8.

I know that I can design a query like this:

```
SELECT child, sys_connect_by_path(child,'/')
   FROM T
  START WITH parent = 2
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR child = PARENT;
```

The problem with such a query is that it will go through all possible paths until they cycle, and there are way too many of them in my actual data. The result consists of many duplicates – Here it is:

```
child | sys_connect_by_path (for information)
3     | /3
4     | /3/4
5     | /3/4/5
8     | /3/4/5/8
6     | /3/4/5/8/6
6     | /3/6
5     | /3/6/5
8     | /3/6/5/8
4     | /4
5     | /4/5
8     | /4/5/8
6     | /4/5/8/6
8     | /8
6     | /8/6
5     | /8/6/5
```

My actual data is much more complex. the cost of execution of such a query is so huge that my TEMP tablespace, which was autoextendable, reached 10Gb (originally 500 Mb) and my database actually broke because of disk full.

I tried to design the query like this (recursive WITH clause) :

```
WITH descendants(node) AS
( SELECT 2 node FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  (
  SELECT child
    FROM T
   INNER JOIN descendants D
      ON T.parent = D.node
   MINUS SELECT node FROM descendants
  )
)
SELECT * FROM descendants
```

The problem that I encounter is:

- with Oracle 10g, this is not implemented (`ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing`, and some customers use Oracle 9 or 10),
- with Oracle 11g, I get `ORA-32041: UNION ALL operation in recursive WITH clause must have only two branches`. If I remove the MINUS clause I will get cycles (`ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query`).

How would you query my original data to get those nodes 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 efficiently? PL/SQL solutions are also welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your expected maximum depth to reach any child node?

If it's relatively small, you could loop down, while checking for nodes you have already visited, in a manner something like this...

(Note, I'm not an Oracle expert so this is closer to pseudo code with a little real SQL mixed in)

```
CREATE TABLE myMap (parent INT, child INT);

INSERT INTO myTable SELECT NULL, 2 FROM DUAL;

WHILE (SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0)
LOOP

  INSERT INTO
    myMap
  SELECT DISTINCT
    dataMap.parent,
    dataMap.child
  FROM
    myMap
  INNER JOIN
    dataMap
      ON myMap.child = dataMap.parent
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myMap WHERE parent = dataMap.parent)

END LOOP;
```

Depending on performance, you may also want a `depth` field in `myMap`; optimising the join so as to only join on the most recent nodes.  This would imply two indexes; one for the JOIN `(depth)` and one for the NOT EXISTS `(parent)`.

**EDIT**

Added the DISTINCT key word, to avoid the following case...
- Node 2 maps to 3 and 4
- Nodes 3 and 4 both map to node 5
- All children of node 5 would now be processed twice

GROUP BY, or many other options, can be used to cater for this instead of DISTINCT.  It's just that the NOT EXISTS on it's own is not sufficient.

Comment: this looks good, thank you. Is this a case for having a global temporary table?

Comment: I wouldn't want the table to be global.  Imagine the mess that could happen if two processes started using it together?  (It's already open to 'unusual' behavior if the source table is modified mid-execution.  But you can protect the whole thing in a transaction if you need to.)

Comment: @Dems: Just a note about _global temporary tables_ as you stated you're not an Oracle expert. In Oracle things are different: [What is the difference between a temporary table vs global temporary table in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/417764) and [Creating a Temporary Table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/tables003.htm#ADMIN11633)

Comment: Then the answer to Benoit's question is simply "yes" :)

Comment: @Dems: I have implemented as a function that returns a `TABLE OF OBJECT` following the spirit of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with this myself, but what about a CONNECT BY with the NOCYCLE option? That should stop travering the tree when it sees a loop. Oracle 11i definitely has that, I think it came in somewhere in the Oracle 10g period.

Comment: `connect by` works like a charm. See example here: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by_nocycle.html

Comment: Thanks for answering, but -1: Re-read my question, I am currently using CONNECT BY and it is not performing well on that type of data.

Answer (score 1):

This might help until visited exceeds 4000 bytes. Cycles should not be possible but the line is there just as an example.

```
   WITH descendants(node, lvl, pth, visited) AS
    (
    SELECT child node, 1, cast(child as varchar2(4000)), '/'||listagg(child,'/') within group (order by child) over()||'/'
      FROM t 
     where parent = 2
     UNION ALL
    SELECT child, lvl+1, pth||'/'||child, D.visited||listagg(child,'/') within group (order by child) over()||'/'
      FROM T
     INNER JOIN descendants D
        ON T.parent = D.node
     WHERE D.visited not like '%/'||child||'/%'
    )
    cycle node set cyc to '1' default '0' 
    SELECT distinct node
      FROM descendants
     order by node
    ;
```